# Is the language of Turing machines that calculate a given function $f$ in RE or coRE?

Tags: computability

For a function $f$, consider the language $$L=\{\langle M\rangle\mid M\text{ computes }f\}\,.$$

Where does the language above is and how do I prove it?
To me it seems that it's not in RE nor coRE but I struggle to prove so.
what I have so far is reduction from HP to $L$ as follows:

$$R(<M>,w) = <M'>$$
$$
Define \ M': \\ M(w) \\  
\qquad \qquad \qquad Write \ x \ on \ the \ tape$$

$$ 1. \ Run \ M \ on \ W \\
   2.\ write \ x \ on \ the \ tape $$

But I can't prove that this language is in RE.

So how do I proceed from here ?

Comment: I don't understand your reduction. Can you explain in words what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Below, we assume $f$ computable, otherwise $L$ is empty, so RE and coRE.

## For the "RE" part

This can be done with reductions, but the easy way is to exploit the Rice-Shapiro theorem.

Now, take a set of partial recursive functions $F$ ($F=\{f\}$, in your case), and define $L$ to be the set of TMs that implement some function in $F$.
If $L$ happens to be in RE, then by Rice-Shapiro we must have

1. if $g\in F$ has infinite domain, some finite restriction of $g$ must belong to $F$ as well
2. if $g$ is non-total, every computable extension of $g$ must belong to $F$

Often, one of these cases is false, implying that $L$ was not RE (provided it has the form above).

In your case, $L$ can not be RE since $F$ only contains $f$: if $f$ has an infinite domain, 1) is violated, otherwise 2) is violated.

In both these cases, you can replace Rice-Shapiro by suitable reductions from the complement of the halting problem, but doing that you are essentially repeating the proof of Rice-Shapiro. It is still a nice exercise, though: one can define one reduction for each case.

Even more in general, $F$ can never be finite if $L$ is RE. But $F=\{f\}$ is finite.

## For the "coRE" part

If $f$ is the always-undefined function, $L$ is coRE. Indeed, for $M$ to implement a different function from $f$, it is enough that $M$ halts on some input, which is a RE problem.

If $f$'s domain is nonempty, say $f(x)=y$, $L$ is not coRE. To prove that, it suffices to reduce the halting problem to $L$. 
Given $M$, craft $M'$ which on input $w\neq x$ outputs $f(w)$. When $w=x$, instead, run $M$, and if that halts output $y$ (otherwise we diverge).